# MIPS Assembly - Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, assembly, architecture, mips

I'm trying to make a programm that calculates the greatest common divisor between two numbers using a recursive function. The problem is the programm seems to calculate the right answer at the first time it reaches the "exitmdc" function, after that it should return to the main function but instead it is returning to the GCD function (called mdc because it's in portuguese). The result changes because of that. I don't know what's causing this issue because the recursive functions that I've seen seem to work this way.

C++ Function:

```
    int rec_mdc(int x, int y) { 
        if(x==y)
            return x;
        else if (x < y) 
            return rec_mdc(x, y-x); 
        else 
            return rec_mdc(x, x–y); 
        } 
    }
```

My Assembly programm:

```
.data


    InformaPrimeiro: .asciiz "Informe um numero: "
    InformaSegundo: .asciiz "\nInforme um segundo numero: "
    novaLinha: .asciiz "\n"


.text   

    main: 
        jal insereNumero
        jal mdc

        add $a0,$v0,$zero 
        li $v0,1
        syscall 


    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    insereNumero:

        li $v0,4 # Informa ao computador que uma string/texto está sendo impresso
        la $a0, InformaPrimeiro # Carrega o endereço no registrador de argumentos 
        syscall # Chamada do sistema

        #Escolha do usuário: 
        li $v0,5 # 5 corresponde aos inteiros
        syscall

        move $a1, $v0


        li $v0,4
        la $a0, InformaSegundo 
        syscall

        li $v0,5
        syscall

        move $a2, $v0

        jr $ra



    mdc:

        addi $sp, $sp, -12 # colocaremos 3 itens na pilha
        sw $a1, 0 ($sp) # salvamos o argumento n    
        sw $a2, 4 ($sp) # salvamos o argumento n2
        sw $ra, 8 ($sp) # salvamos o endereço de retorno


        beq  $a1,$a2,exitmdc        
        blt  $a1, $a2, if
        bgt $a1, $a2, else

     if:
        sub $a2, $a2, $a1
        jal mdc

     else:
        sub $a1, $a1, $a2
        jal  mdc



    exitmdc:
        add $v0, $zero, $a1


        lw $ra, 8($sp)
        lw $a2, 4($sp)
        lw $a1, 0($sp)

        addi $sp, $sp, 12 
        jr $ra
```

The "insereNumero" function is just for the user input

Comment: Since it's recursive the first time it hits `exitmdc` it will return to its caller which is another `mdc` (one of the earlier `jal mdc`). Your problem is that the `if` and `else` branches fall through into each other and into `exitmdc`.

Comment: Also, your printing code will screw up the return value (`$v0`). I don't see why the printing code should be part of `mcd` since it has nothing to do with calculating the GCD. Let the `main` code print the result instead.

Comment: @Jester should I put something after the **jal mdc** in if/else functions like another **jr $ra** ?? (I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if this sounds stupid)

Comment: @Michael sorry, there wasn't a printing code there, I just put one so I could see what was happening, I'll remove it

Comment: Both your `if` and `else` branch ought to jump to the instruction after `add $v0, $zero, $a1` after their respective `jal`.

Comment: @Michael it worked, thank you!!

Comment: @Michael actually it didn't, I guess I did something wrong.. It worked for just a few numbers, I tried to do something like `j return` after their respective `jal` and in return I have `add $v0, $zero, $a1` and `j exitmdc`

Comment: My point was that you should NOT execute `add $v0, $zero, $a1` in those cases. That is, you should jump straight to where you start loading the saved registers from the stack.

Comment: @Michael oh I see, my bad. It's working now, thanks